# numpy.show_config says "ATLAS unavailable" but np.dot seems use multi core

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

I use anaconda on OSX. I hope to allow numpy to use multi-core.

My numpy.show_config() seems to show atlas is not available yet (or use blas and lapack??? Sorry, I'm a novice around here.):

```
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

but when numpy.matrix.dot function runs, python process use several cores:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([])
for i in range(20000):
    a = np.append(a,i/100.0)
m = np.matrix([a])
for _ in range(12):
    m = np.vstack([m,m])
m.dot(m.T) # => product of large matrix
```

The activity monitor tells me approximately seven cores are used during above code is executed.
[image: activity monitor tells me approximately seven cores are used]

I'm confused with what happens...? I'd like to know at least numpy run in multi-thread way.

Answer (score 0):

The output tells you that it's using the [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009465), the BLAS/LAPACK library provided by Apple on OSX. You don't especially need Atlas or Openblas on OSX, Accelerate is multithreaded and probably about as good as the others in practice.